# Measuring time spent in a http request with OpenTelemetry

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, open-telemetry

I often write various API services in ASP.NET Core using C# and ASP.NET Core 7 or 8 with EF Core and Postgres as database. Pretty straight forward.

Sometimes when it takes too much time to execute API queries, I try to troubleshoot using OpenTelemetry/tracing and it usually points to a slow query or something. However, I keep notice that some requests takes a decent time to complete, say 500ms, but only 5-10ms registered by EF Core instrumentation for SQL queries.

Is there any good instrumentation I'm missing or any good setting to figure out where the time is spent?

Profiling is an option but less than optimal in a production environment and these quirks does not appear locally.

I'm using the following instrumentations:

```
AddHttpClientInstrumentation
AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation
AddEntityFrameworkCoreInstrumentation
AddSqlClientInstrumentation
```

Example of a long trace with lot's of void and two short EF Core Postgres queries. Service is running in Azure AKS.

[image: Plot of Trace with two short EF Core queries and lots of void]

Answer (score 0):

This where you should start adding your own Activity instances through the flow of code, that will give you more ideas of where to look.

Right now, you're adding the instrumentation libraries, and that's great. The true power comes from adding Activity objects around your own code to see how that's functioning too.